# can't import markdown in Django project file

Tags: python, django, import, markdown

I'm having issues importing markdown in the blog_tags.py file I created or anywhere else.
I installed it with the line "pip install markdown" and it installed successfully. I checked with "pip freeze" and it is there.
However, when I try to import markdown in a .py file it says it can't find the module.
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72PvP.png)

sample code:

```
from django import template
from ..models import Post
from django.db.models import Count
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
import markdown


register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def total_posts():
    return Post.published.count()

@register.inclusion_tag('blog/post/latest_posts.html')
def show_latest_posts(count=5):
    latest_posts = Post.published.order_by('-publish')[:count]
    return {'latest_posts': latest_posts}
@register.simple_tag
def get_most_commented_posts(count=5):
    return Post.published.annotate(
        total_comments=Count('comments')
    ).order_by('-total_comments')[:count]  

@register.filter(name='markdown')
def markdown_format(text):
    return mark_safe(markdown.markdown(text))
```

Have a nice day everyone

Comment: Does PyCharm points to the interpreter of your virtual environment?

Comment: I think this will help you https://exerror.com/import-flask-could-not-be-resolved-from-source-pylance/#:~:text=source%20pylance%20Error%20%3F-,To%20Solve%20Import%20flask%20could%20not%20be%20resolved%20from%20source,you%20installed%20inside%20this%20virtualenv.

Comment: it is probable that you have 2 Python installations and `pip` installing in one but your IDE is pointing at the other. Start by doing `pip --version` and compare what it says with what your IDE thinks the interpreter is.